# Django IntegrityError signup_simplesubscriber.date_created may not be NULL

Tags: django, django-forms

I've read every "InterityError" + "may no be NULL" post and still can't track down what's causing this error.

I've got a two-part signup form.  First part is just selecting a product.  That passes a product ID to the next page as part of the URL, where they input personal info. I can get the form to work fine until I start removing fields -- i'm using model forms -- because some fields don't need to be displayed.

Here's my model, and the modelForm:

```
class SimpleSubscriber(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    sub_type = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class SubscriberForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SimpleSubscriber
        fields = ('name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'phone', 'email', 'sub_type',)#'date_created',
```

And here's my views:

```
def select_product(request):
    title = "get yourself an e-edition. wurd."
    pform = Product.objects.order_by('product_active')  
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        pform = ProductForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if pform.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass 
        # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('signup/%i' % pform.id) # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ProductForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response('signup/index.html', {'title': title, 'pform': pform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def subscriber_signup(request, product_id):
    productchoice = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    title = "We need some information."  
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        sform = SubscriberForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if sform.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            sform.date_created = now
            sform.sub_type = productchoice
            sform.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thankyou/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        sform = SubscriberForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response('signup/detail.html', {'title': title, 'sform': sform, 'productchoice': productchoice, 'now': now.date(),}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I think it has something to do with the modelForm, but I'm pretty new, so I really have no idea.  If I add all the fields to SubscriberForm, then they get filled out and everything works fine. But I don't want users to have to say when they filled out the form, so i put sform.date_created = now and I want the product_id to be filled in automatically by what choice they picked on the previous page.  but if I exclude these fields from the form it throws the IntegrityError, which isn't very helpful in explaining what to change.

Any hints on where I'm messing up?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) You may benefit from using exlude in your form definition:

```
class SubscriberForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SimpleSubscriber
        exclude = ('date_created', )
```

2) To your question, heres how to fix it:

```
if sform.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass

    suscriber = sform.save(commit=False)
    suscriber.date_created = now
    suscriber.sub_type = productchoice
    suscriber.save()
```

Comment: That is awesome.  Definitely fixed the error.  Why commit=False?  What is that doing and is the order of these commands important? I'd assume the sform.save(commit=False) has to go first and subscriber.save() last?

Comment: The job of the form's save method, is to process it's data and return an object. If you tell it not to commit, that means it will do that, but without the database sync part.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @fceruti's suggestion, you can also add more kwarg tags `null=True` on the model's field where appropriate - only forcing a minimal set of fields to be completed in the form.